# Different values when converting Instant to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, kotlin, java-time

I receive a time in UTC format from the server. I parse to an `Instant` object and then convert it to `LocalDateTime`. Like so:

```
fun String.toLocaleDateTime(): LocalDateTime {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.parse(this), 
        ZoneOffset.systemDefault()
    )
}
```

The issue is that for different years the `LocalDateTime` object is different.

For example when converting UTC time to IST time:

1800-01-01T03:36:32Z -> 1800-01-01T09:30
1870-01-01T03:36:32Z -> 1870-01-01T08:57:42
1906-01-01T03:36:32Z -> 1906-01-01T09:06:32

[Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: what is the default time zone?

Comment: what do you mean? Im converting UTC to IST as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @KeyserSöze You are using the default timezone: `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()`. What is your default time zone?

Comment: pretty sure that India changed its time zone a couple of times... (I meant something like the result of  `ZoneOffset.systemDefault()`, but never mind I'm almost sure its India)

Comment: Ohh. Ill check that out. Thanks

Comment: time zone was changed 1854, 1870, 1906, 1941, 1942, 1945, ... e.g. check [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/india/kolkata)

Comment: @user15244370 You are right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I believe Java uses data updated from the [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database)

Comment: Yes its the default. [Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)

Comment: One thing is sure. In year 1800, no country in the world had any concept of time zones. We should even prohibit such nonsense conversions. That means: You use the wrong type (`Instant`) for those early years (better: just use `LocalDate`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's get all the changes in offset for India from 1700 to 2000:

```
ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").rules.transitions.filter {
    (1700..2000).contains(it.dateTimeBefore.year)
}.forEach {
    println("On ${it.dateTimeBefore}, jumped from ${it.offsetBefore} to ${it.offsetAfter}")
}
```

This will get the timezone data on the version of tzdb on your machine. On my machine, this prints:

```
On 1854-06-28T00:00, jumped from +05:53:28 to +05:53:20
On 1870-01-01T00:00, jumped from +05:53:20 to +05:21:10
On 1906-01-01T00:00, jumped from +05:21:10 to +05:30
On 1941-10-01T00:00, jumped from +05:30 to +06:30
On 1942-05-15T00:00, jumped from +06:30 to +05:30
On 1942-09-01T00:00, jumped from +05:30 to +06:30
On 1945-10-15T00:00, jumped from +06:30 to +05:30
```

It seems like until 1906, India was using [local mean time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time).

Each of your results reflect these offsets:

- In 1800, the offset was +05:53:28, that added to 03:36:32 is exactly 09:30
- In 1870, the offset was the offset was +05:21:10, that added to 03:36:32 is exactly 08:57:42
- In 1906, the offset was standardised to +05:30, giving you the answer that you probably expected.

Comment: As an aside, https://nodatime.org/tzvalidate/generate?zone=Asia/Kolkata will give that data too - no code required. Remove the zone parameter to generate all zones; add a version parameter (e.g. `version=2020d`) to specify an IANA version.