# C# - .net core DateTime conversion to UTC minutes offset

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-core

I was testing a code and found a very strange behavior. When I use `DateTime.MinValue`, add minutes to it, and convert it to UTC, there appears to be a difference of 58 minutes between my local time zone and UTC. I am in central Europe (+1 in winter or +2 in summer). How can this be 58 minutes? I would expect 1 hour offset not 58 minutes. I am using .net core on Linux.

```cs
var x1 = DateTime.MinValue.AddMinutes(61);
var x1ticks = x1.Ticks;
var x1kind = x1.Kind;
var y1 = x1.ToUniversalTime();
var y1tickes = y1.Ticks;
var y1kind = y1.Kind;

var z1 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(x1, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
var z1ticks = z1.Ticks;
var z1kind = z1.Kind;
```

**code snippet with evaluated values**:
[image: code snippet with evaluated values]

Comment: are you running by putting breakpoints?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

58 minutes is approximately the offset from UTC of the [local mean time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/local-mean-time.html) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time)) of Prague, Czech Republic. My guess is that your local timezone is `Europe/Prague`.

`TimeZoneInfo` looks up the timezone data from the timezone database on your computer. On a Linux machine (and all POSIX ones, I think) the default is the IANA [`tz` Database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). On Windows computers you'd be querying the Windows timezone database by default.

Anyway, the important thing is, according to the IANA database, the UTC offset of your local timezone at `DateTime.MinValue` plus 61 minutes, is plus 58 minutes.

```
// prints 00:58:00
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Europe/Prague").GetUtcOffset(DateTime.MinValue));
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66456630/different-values-when-converting-instant-to-localdatetime/66456985#66456985).

The IANA database *actually* says that the offset is 57 minutes and 44 seconds, but .NET Core actually rounds it as an implementation detail, because it doesn't support seconds. I found this [line](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/TimeZoneInfo.Unix.cs,992) of the source code that explains it:

```
    private static TimeSpan TZif_CalculateTransitionOffsetFromBase(TimeSpan transitionOffset, TimeSpan timeZoneBaseUtcOffset)
    {
        TimeSpan result = transitionOffset - timeZoneBaseUtcOffset;

        // TZif supports seconds-level granularity with offsets but TimeZoneInfo only supports minutes since it aligns
        // with DateTimeOffset, SQL Server, and the W3C XML Specification
        if (result.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute != 0)
        {
            result = new TimeSpan(result.Hours, result.Minutes, 0);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: If anyone needs +0:57:44, they can always use my Noda Time project - I've just checked, and that reports it correctly :)